# Is it possible to send an advanced query to Shopify /search url

Tags: pagination, shopify, liquid

I am customizing a Shopify template has a form like this.

```
      <form action="/search" method="get" class="search-bar" role="search">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">
        <input type="search" name="q" class="text" placeholder="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}" value="{{ search.terms }}">
        <input type="hidden" class="btn" value="Search">
      </form>
```

Which returns an array of objects `search.results` it is not possible to remove elements from that array in Liquid (*ex. remove products which has a price of 0*)

I want to remove elements from that array because even though i can filter those elements and choose them to show in the page or not, i cant effect `{% paginate %}` function because it is paginating the unfiltered version of `search.results` for example `{% paginate search.results by 12 %}`.

So my question is can i send an advanced query from the very start and only get the result *for ex. products which have not a price of 0* ?

Thanks in advance.
I googled about this a lot but couldn't find a solution.

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope you can't. Price is not a valid field in Shopify's search fields - https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/online-store/storefront-search

Alternatively you can tag the products with 0 price and add "-*tag*" as a field to exclude those items. Refer to the link for detailed description on search on Shopify.